# How to find a specific type of a derived component inside a vector of base components?

Tags: c++, vector

I dont know if it's possible or not, but i would like to know if it's.
Let say I have a vector of base components like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> m_components;
```

To Add to this components vector I have an **Add()** Method which looks like this:

```
template<class T>
    bool Add() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, " T must be derived from Component");
        if (!DuplicatesExist<T>()) {
            m_components.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(*this));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So if I wanted to add an **Input** component to the vector of components, which is derived from Component I would do this:

```
 container.Add<Input>();
```

So lets say I wanted this **Input** Component because I would like to use the non-derived methods inside of Input. I would like to do something along these lines: `container.Get<Input>();`

```
     template<class T>
            std::unique_ptr<T> &Get() {
                static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, " it have to be derived from component");
                auto& index = std::find_if(m_components.begin(), m_components.end(),
                                     [](auto &C) -> bool {
                                       // what to do here??
                                       if(std::is_same_v<T, C>)
                                           return true;
                                     });

                return index;
}
```

unfortunately that is not possible :(

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want simplest solution or the most efficient.

Simplest would be calling `dynamic_cast`. Assuming `component` is of type `Component*` and `T` is possible derived, `dynamic_cast<T*>(component)` would return non-nullptr `T*` if it is T*, or `nullptr` otherwise.

The most efficient is to replace your vector with [Boost.PolyCollection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/poly_collection.html) container `base_collection`.

There are some options in between. One would be adding a field or a virtual method to base class that would return different values for derived classes. Then if you know the component is of type T, you cast `static_cast` a pointer or a reference, like `static_cast<T&>(component)`. Contrary intuitive, such ad-hoc implementation of `dynamic_cast` may perform faster than generic `dynamic_cast<T*>(component)`.

Comment: Thank You very much! this answers all my questions I have :)

Answer (score 0):

First I have some remarks:

```
 if (!DuplicatesExist<T>())
```

What do you want to check? If your pointer is an duplicate as it points to the same instance? If so, you can directly use a `std::set` instead of a vector!

```
 m_components.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(*this));
```

This will generate a new object as a copy from the object "this". So you will get always a new object and a pointer which contains the address of that one which is never equal to any other one! Is this your intention?

And if in this case `m_components` is a member of the derived class itself, do we want to get a full copy of all elements? Something is very mysterious here :-)

OK, but back to the question:

One solution: Use your own handcrafted "tag" for each type. This code is a bit large and not very convenient:

```
class Base
{   
    public:
        enum Id { ONE, TWO };
        virtual Id GetId() const = 0;
};  

class A: public Base
{   
    public:
    static constexpr Id id = ONE;
    Id GetId() const override { return id; }

    std::string someParm;

    void AFunc() { std::cout << "A-Func" << someParm << std::endl; }

    A( const std::string& parm ): someParm{ parm } {}
};  

class B: public Base
{   
    public:
    static constexpr Id id = TWO;
    Id GetId() const override { return id; }

    void BFunc() { std::cout << "B-Func" << std::endl; }
};  

template < typename T, typename CONTAINER >
T* Get( CONTAINER &objects )
{   
    auto it = std::find_if( objects.begin(), objects.end(), []( std::unique_ptr<Base>& ptr ) { return ptr->GetId() == T::id; } );

    if ( it != objects.end() ) return static_cast<T*>( it->get() );
    return nullptr;
}   


int main()
{
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> > objects;

    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<A> ("Hallo") );
    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<B> () );

    auto ptra = Get< A >( objects );
    if ( ptra ) ptra->AFunc();

    auto ptrb = Get< B >( objects );
    if ( ptrb ) ptrb->BFunc();
}
```

Or you use `dynamic_cast` which needs at minimum one virtual function in your base class and have RTTI enabled for your compiler which is typically not possible on small embedded devices!

```
class Base
{   
    virtual void SomeFunc() {}; 
};  

class A: public Base
{   
    public:
        std::string someParm;
        void AFunc() { std::cout << "A-Func" << someParm << std::endl; }
        A( const std::string& parm ): someParm{ parm } {}
};  

class B: public Base
{   
    public:
        void BFunc() { std::cout << "B-Func" << std::endl; }
};  

    template < typename T, typename CONTAINER >
T* Get( CONTAINER &objects )
{   
    T* ret;
    for ( auto& ptr:  objects )
    {   
        Base* base = ptr.get();
        ret = dynamic_cast<T*>( base );
        if ( ret ) return ret;
    }   

    return nullptr; 
}


int main()
{
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> > objects;
    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<A> ("Hallo") );
    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<B> () );

    auto ptra = Get< A >( objects );
    if ( ptra ) ptra->AFunc();

    auto ptrb = Get< B >( objects );
    if ( ptrb ) ptrb->BFunc();
}
```

or use `std::variant`

```
class A 
{   
    public:
        std::string someParm;
        void AFunc() { std::cout << "A-Func" << someParm << std::endl; }
        A( const std::string& parm ): someParm{ parm } {}
};  

class B
{   
    public:
        void BFunc() { std::cout << "B-Func" << std::endl; }
};

using VAR_T = std::variant< std::unique_ptr<A>, std::unique_ptr<B> >;

int main()
{   
    std::vector< VAR_T > objects;
    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<A> ("Hallo") );
    objects.emplace_back( std::make_unique<B> () );

    for ( auto& ptr: objects )
    {

        std::visit( []( auto& lptr )
                   {   
                       using T = std::decay_t<decltype(lptr)>;
                       if constexpr ( std::is_same< T, std::unique_ptr<A> >::value )
                       {
                           lptr->AFunc();
                       }
                       else if constexpr ( std::is_same< T, std::unique_ptr<B> >::value )
                       {
                           lptr->BFunc();
                       }
                   }
                   , ptr );
    }
}
```

The last one seems to be the easiest way for me. It comes without much additional cost. Only the "tag" is stored inside the variant, but as the variant containing only different pointers of same size, there is no additional cost for size of the variant here. And you can still use it on small embedded devices, as you do not need RTTI. In addition, you do not need a virtual function and you also do not need to derive from a base class. So it is highly flexible!

Comment: So, the thing I’m trying to achieve is this:
I want a container that consist of different components, but only 1 type of component is allowed, this means I can add the “Input” component once, but not twice. These components should be able to talk/broadcast information to each other through some messaging system. Every component needs to derive from the base (which is Component).  So, to answer your question for the DuplicatesExist<T>. It checks if there is a derived <T> type already in the container, if so, I don’t want to add an instance of that type again.